# How can I specify where I want my tikz image to be placed?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to have text and then to the right of the text is a tikz image ? I know we can centre the tikz image in the middle of the page but can we have it to the complete right or any other place on the page we desire?

[image]

Comment: Look for `wrapfigure` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! First, this seems not to be related to Overleaf. Second, it highly depends. You should provide a more concrete example to give us a hint of what you want to achieve.

Comment: It depends on how you're making your image.  You've not given us much to go on.  Overleaf is unrelated to your question, but their documentation for [positioning figures](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_images_and_tables) mentions "Wrapping text around a figure".

Comment: @DhruvNair would you like to add a hand sketch of the desired output

Comment: Yes @jsbibra done

Answer (score 1):

With a picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mwe}
    \usepackage{graphbox} %loads graphicx package
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            text & \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image}\\ %<<--- align=b is the default option
            text & \includegraphics[align=c,scale=0.5]{example-image} \\
            text & \includegraphics[align=t,scale=0.35]{example-image} \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

With a tikz graph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\begin{document}        
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=1]
        \node[blue] at (-180:4) (t) {\bf TEXT};
        \coordinate (a) at (220:2); 
        \coordinate (b) at (90:2);
        \coordinate (c) at (0:2);
            
        \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (a) node[left] {$\vec{i}$};
        \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (b) node[right] {$\vec{k}$};
        \draw[->,thick,black] (0,0) -- (c) node[right] {$\vec{j}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Its not a node though, I have text and then my tikz. I basically want the text to be left aligned as normal and then the tikz graph to be on the right hand side next to the left aligned text

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Some text.
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift=(current page.north west), x={(current page.north east)}, y={(current page.south west)}]
  \fill[red] (0.5, 0.5) circle[radius=1 cm];
  \fill[green] (0.15, 0.15) circle[radius=1 cm];
  \fill[blue] (1, 1) circle[radius=1 cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A page with red, green and blue circle]